# Laravel 9 Ubuntu constant permission errors

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I've deployed my Laravel app on Ubuntu Server 20.04 and I've had nothing but problems with permissions. The app itself works, I can view it on localhost (I don't need it publicly accessible.)

But no matter what I do, it just spews file permission errors and it makes absolutely no sense.

1. Try run a composer command? That's a permissions error.
2. Try git pull? That's a permissions error.
3. Try log why it's having permissions errors? That's also a permissions error.
4. Try export a spreadsheet from my site and store it? That's also a permissions error.
5. Do the forbidden `chmod 777` on the entire site directory so it couldn't possibly have permissions errors? It still complains about permissions.
6. Even running commands as sudo 90% of the time gives me some nanny-style message about how I "shouldn't be doing this" and refuses to let me progress, even though there is a perfectly valid reason I'm doing it, and for the 10% of times it does let me run it, guess what, it's still permissions errors.

I really don't understand how anyone can stay sane and set this up. I followed exactly what everyone recommends on every stackoverflow post in existence about this topic of creating a new user, adding it to `www-data`, etc... and it just refuses to give permissions. When attempting to troubleshoot, nothing is possible because of these stupid permission errors and everyone just says "temporarily" `chmod 777`, which I've already tried and apparently even giving 777 still isn't high enough permissions for it?

I've wiped my Ubuntu install twice and followed multiple different guides online word for word and I just don't understand anymore. Can someone please provide some insight? I do not understand why it has to be this hard, when previously I setup a Laravel app on Ubuntu about a year ago and it took me all of about 30 minutes to get it fully operational with 0 issues.

Comment: do you apply the `chmod 777` recursively? what is the exact error message can you see the logs (including `php` log)? how did you install composer? there are too many moving parts in a single question, we need to pin point a bit.

Comment: ok you need to read and comprehend the *NIX permission system. The errors you are getting usually come with a specific file and / or folder that is not accessible. Check those specific ones on (a) who owns them (b) what permissions they have and then also check (a) which user is running the commands (e.g. is it your current user or are they running as another user). (b) what group the user running the commands belongs to. It's not uncommon to find guides in the internet that ask you to run things as `sudo` but this may end up putting files in your home folder that belong to root.

Comment: Permissions errors always relate to WHO you are trying the action as and WHO the files are owned by.  You cannot run a php artisan command that changes the file system if the files are owned by another user.  Yes, you can blast through the permissions with 777 but as soon as the web server creates some files (eg cache, log or session files) then they will be owned by the www-data account and not you - meaning you can then not perform commands that would for instance add to logs

Answer (score 1):

Just to state the obvious for anyone viewing this discussion.... if you give any of your folders 777 permissions, you are allowing ANYONE to read, write and execute any file in that directory.

IF YOU ARE SETTING YOUR FOLDER PERMISSIONS TO 777 YOU HAVE OPENED YOUR SERVER TO ANYONE THAT CAN FIND THAT DIRECTORY. Clear enough??? :)

There are basically two ways to setup your ownership and permissions. Either you give yourself ownership or you make the webserver the owner of all files.

#### Webserver as owner (the way most people do it, and the Laravel doc's way):

assuming **www-data** (it could be something else) is your webserver user.

```
    sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory
```

if you do that, the webserver owns all the files, and is also the group, and you will have some problems uploading files or working with files via FTP, because your FTP client will be logged in as you, not your webserver, so add your user to the webserver user group:

```
    sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu
```

Of course, this assumes your webserver is running as www-data (the Homestead default), and your user is ubuntu (it's vagrant if you are using Homestead).

Then you set all your directories to 755 and your files to 644...

###### SET file permissions

sudo find /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;

###### SET directory permissions

sudo find /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;

#### Your user as owner

I prefer to own all the directories and files (it makes working with everything much easier), so, go to your laravel root directory:

```
    cd /var/www/html/laravel  // assuming this is your current root directory

    sudo chown -R $USER:www-data .
```

Then I give both myself and the webserver permissions:

```
    sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;   
    sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

Then give the webserver the rights to read and write to storage and cache

Whichever way you set it up, then you need to give read and write permissions to the webserver for storage, cache and any other directories the webserver needs to upload or write too (depending on your situation), so run the commands from bashy above :

sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache

This is a combination of multiple answers which I have as a txt file on my pc and use it every time Im gonna deploy.